# When I in my VM install the Ubuntu, there is no next step button show

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

[image]

You see the image upper, when I install the Ubuntu, I can not click the next step button here, you see the right button there is half of the return button, the interface did not show whole interface.

---

**EDIT**

My PC is MBP, and the workstation is VMware Fusion.

Comment: try setting the video for the VM to a larger screen

Comment: do you mean to join up a bigger screen? My mac is 13 inch

Comment: the screen resolution not physical size. it appears that you have a very low screen resolution (640x400)

Comment: @ravery, It doesn't work. setup always uses a low resolution screen in VM even if I set size of the screen to 1600x900, the screen during setup is always 800x600